# Labeling data entries with MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is it possible add label as sample name over the entries points in MPAndroidChart?

Example: [image](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qkDz89dyzls/Ug1XbG7UH1I/AAAAAAAABB4/kpWo_Bu5R2c/s1600/showhide2.png)